# Is lord Dattatreya a Chiranjeevi?

Tags: vishnu, vedic-gods, manuscripts, dattatreya, dattaopnishad

I have read somewhere that guru Dattatreya still resides in the Sahyadri mountains. Is this true

Comment: Dattatreya Upanishad in second khanda describes DattTreya like “Mahayogi, Avadhuta, son of Atri and Anasuya. Then it also mentions “chiranjeevine”. https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_upanishhat/dattatreya.pdf